# Linux and grub fix to load windows

Tags: boot, grub2

My DVD drive is not working properly and I had formatted Linux partition while upgrading.
It fails due to media error and Im thinking the grub file is deleted perhaps. I have Windows 7 as other OS.

Tell me how to boot from Windows 7 without using DVD and with help of grub rescue?

Comment: Please avoid using SMS writings.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to boot windows from grub rescue prompt. Grub rescue contains very few commands which allow you to load modules (e.g. from a grub rescue disk).

So you need a bootable medium. If you have access to any other system build a bootable usb of windows 7 media or other boot cds like [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/), [Hirens boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/) or may be use [boot-repair-disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/)

Boot using windows 7 media/ boot-repair-disk and perform startup repair.